# Capifony error failed: "sh -c 'git

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, symfony, capifony

I am trying to deploy my symfony 2 application with capifony, i've read the documentation but i can't seem to find the solution for my error.

```
failed: "sh -c 'git clone -q git@***.org:***/***.git public_html/new/releases/20121214201830 && cd public_html/new/releases/20121214201830 && git checkout -q -b deploy f2438d8b8873e7af474c7ad6111090dadc106de0 && (echo f2438d8b8873e7af474c7ad6111090dadc106de0 > public_html/new/releases/20121214201830/REVISION)'" on ***.hostgator.com
```

I have shell access to the webhost and the repository is working fine with ssh

I hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, for people who were spending hours on this, here is the solution.

- First of all you should enable the logging in your deploy.rb on the maximum level so you can see every error message and not just "failed".
  to do this do:

  ## IMPORTANT = 0

  ## INFO      = 1

  ## DEBUG     = 2

  ## TRACE     = 3

  ## MAX_LEVEL = 3

  logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL

that's the most important part, then i got a message about my public key not being correct, just copy your ssh key from your local computer to the computer you want to deploy to and also make sure that your ssh key is in your git account

Hope this saves some time for people